# Powershell behavior under different user accounts

Tags: powershell

When I run Powershell under my account or under admin account, the tasks in my script are executed one after another. When I run it under another account, the tasks are started together, which is undesired behavior. How can I fix this?

```
$scriptBlock = {
    function runTasks()
    {
        C:\startTask1.ps1
        C:\startTask2.ps1
        C:\startTask3.ps1
        C:\startTask4.ps1
    }
}

Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command & {$ScriptBlock runTasks}"
```

Another observation which may or may not be related - when I start powershell under my account or under "Run as Administrator", I get a window with blue background. If I start with a SHIFT + right-click and select "Run as different user" and provide another account then a window which opens up is black console-like.

EDIT #1:

I split my script into two files:

taskList.ps1

```
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\path\task1.ps1 -arg1 'x1' -arg2 'x2'" -RedirectStandardError task1.txt -wait
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\path\task2.ps1 -arg1 'x3'" -RedirectStandardError task2.txt -wait
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\path\task1.ps1 -arg1 'x4' -arg2 'x5'" -RedirectStandardError task3.txt -wait
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\path\task2.ps1 -arg1 'x6'" -RedirectStandardError task4.txt -wait
```

and taskStarter.ps1

```
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\path\taskList.ps1" -RedirectStandardError taskErr.txt -RedirectStandardOutput taskOut.txt
```

When I run taskStarter.ps1 from a powershell console under my account it works well - all tasks are executing one after another and *-wait* param in taskList.ps1 is obeyed. However when I then run the same taskStarter.ps1 under new account all tasks are running together and *-wait* is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to call `Process.WaitForExit()` on each script you want to run using use the `-PassThru` switch.

```
$process1 = Start-Process <path to script 1> -PassThru
$process1.WaitForExit() 

$process2 = Start-Process <path to script 2> -PassThru
$process2.WaitForExit() 

$process3 = Start-Process <path to script 3> -PassThru
$process3.WaitForExit() 

$process4 = Start-Process <path to script 4> -PassThru
$process4.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that the Scripts are executed one after another, call each one separate with Start-Process and use the Argument "-Wait" in addition.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I followed your advice and replaced my script with:

`Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList "C:\startTask1.ps1 -arg1 'x1'" -RedirectStandardError task1.txt -wait`

this line repeats 4 times with different -AargumentList values. Similarly to original script, the new script works well if I run it under my account but not under powershell that was started under the new account. So I am still at the same place. Any other ideas or things to try?

Comment: Can you try logging the Output of the other Scripts. Maybe they are not executed correct. Security, wrong path etc...

Comment: I tried to output errors with *start-transcript* as well as setting a path to *-RedirectStandardError* when starting a process using *Start-Process* command. No errors were showing and this is mostly due to scripts being very simple as I am trying to establish why the behavior is not consistent. Please see my EDIT #1.